# Blazor: How to change the URL dynamically?

Tags: blazor

I have a page which takes a string bookingReference as its route parameter `Booking/{bookingReference}`.

This page is the parent component, with a child component inside where booking details are managed. The child component calls back to the parent when booking details are updated.

```
@page "/Booking/{bookingReference}"


<div class="header">
   <h1> @Booking.BookingReference </h1>
</div>

<div>
   <BookingDetails Booking="Booking" OnUpdateBooking="UpdateBooking" />
</div>


@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string BookingReference { get; set; }    

    private Booking Booking { get; set; }

    void UpdateBooking(Booking booking)
    {
        Booking = booking;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

The BookingDetails component looks like this:

```
<EditForm Model="FormState" OnValidSubmit="@saveChanges">
   //inputs etc.
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Booking Booking { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<Booking> OnUpdateBooking { get; set; }

private async Task saveChanges()
{
        // update booking object
        Booking.BookingReference = FormState.BookingReference;

        try
        {
            Booking = await BookingService.UpdateBooking(Booking);
            await OnUpdateBooking.InvokeAsync(Booking);
            Toaster.Success("Booking updated successfully");
        }
        catch
        {
            Toaster.Error("Failed to update booking");
        }
    }
}
```

The user can update the booking reference from the child component, and thus, change the header of the page - that works fine, all good.

However, I would also like to change the URL to the updated bookingReference - is there any way I can achieve this without forcing a refresh?

Comment: You must navigate to change url=> NavigationManager.NavigateTo(UrlWithNewReference)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, right now the only way to change the value of the BookingReference in the url is to navigate to the current url with the new BookingReference.
Note that this action is not reloading or refreshing the page component. It is rather a re-rendering action. The OnInitialized life cycle is executed only once, which indicates that the components are not destroyed and then re-created. They are only re-rendered. This is the way to go.

```
@code {

[Parameter]
public string BookingReference { get; set; }    

private Booking Booking { get; set; }

void UpdateBooking(Booking booking)
{
    Booking = booking;
    NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/{Booking.BookingReference}");

}
}
```

Comment: The one possible downside to this approach is that the page will scroll to the top.

Answer (score 2):

If by "forcing a refresh", you mean reloading the page, then the answer is positive. You don't have to reload your page, but you have to re-render the page in order to refresh the view ( not reloading but re-rendering). When you reload a page, the page component and the embedded components are created anew. When you re-render your page the page components and the embedded components are not destroyed, and only Html diffs are applied to reflect this.

You did not post the code for the BookingDetails component, so my answer here is only based on a guess

```
<BookingDetails Booking="Booking" OnUpdateBooking="UpdateBooking" />


Your BookingDetails component should define a property named OnUpdateBooking
of type *EventCallback<Booking>* like this:



[Parameter]
public EventCallback<Booking> OnUpdateBooking {get; set;}
```

It also should define a parameter property named Booking, which is an object passed from the parent component.

```
// Supporting variable
private Booking booking;

[Parameter]
public Booking Booking 
{ 
  get => booking; 
set 
{
   if( booking != value)
   {
      booking = value;
      OnUpdateBooking.InvokeAsync(value);
   } 
}
```

Note: The Booking property stores the value passed from the parent component. When its value changes by code in the child component, you should invoke the OnUpdateBooking 'delegate', passing it the newly updated value. This value is passed back to the UpdateBooking method defined in the parent component, assign the passed value to the private Booking field, and then re-render the parent page. Now you should see the url changes to reflect this.

Note: Remove the call to StateHasChanged method from the UpdateBooking. It is not necessary.

Comment: I've noticed you're regularly helping people out with Blazor issues so first off, thanks.

I updated the question with my child component code, looks like I was doing most of what you did, minus the supporting variable and the getter/setter. I will try and see if this works, cheers.

Comment: What you do is fine...in the sense that it should work...you first call the  BookingService.UpdateBooking to update the Booking object, say in the database, and then invoke the OnUpdateBooking on the parent component.

Comment: OK, I was too vain not to read your whole question. I understand now what you want ... I'll add a new short answer..